# How can I make my PreferenceActivity material designed on Lollipop devices?

Tags: java, android, android-theme, material-design, preferenceactivity

I have a few really simple `PreferenceActivity`s that I'd like to material designed but I'm not quite sure how.

My activity doesn't use any custom styles or themes so I was under the impression that it would automatically adopt the material-design look and feel, but it didn't.

How can I achieve this? Do I need to add a custom `styles.xml`?

Comment: Try out my library here: https://github.com/AndroidDeveloperLB/MaterialPreferenceLibrary . It's not a full solution, but it could be useful.

Answer (score 1):

You should create an Activity and then add a Fragment that extend from PreferenceFragment

```
public class PreferenceActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.preference_layout);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content, new CustomPreferenceFragment()).commit();
    }
}
```

And the Fragment

```
public static class CustomPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragment 
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not extend `PrereferenceActivity`?

Answer (score 0):

In your Manifest file, you can define the theme for your Activity:

```
<activity
    android:name="YourActivity"
    ...
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Material" >
</activity>
```

Please, take a look at the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/material/theme.html)

Also, take into account that

> @android:style/Theme.Material requires API level 21